# Is there any guidance on how to pronounce "Da5id" from Snow Crash?

Tags: names, snow-crash, pronunciation

Has Neil Stephenson ever commented about how the character's name *Da5id* should be pronounced?

Failing that how is the name pronounced in the audio version?

I'm re-reading the book and my inner voice is confused...

Comment: Since 5 is V in a Roman numerals, I'm guessing, *"David"*?

Comment: Thanks, well it is just a guess but, since it seems to make sense and has a couple of upvotes, I'll add it as an answer rather than just a comment.

Comment: Since 5 is spelled with an 'F', his name would be pronounced 'Dafid' rather than 'David'.

Comment: Since Dafydd is a Welsh name, and "f" in Welsh is pronounced like "v" in English, then it would still be pronounced "David" if the "5" stood for "f".

Comment: While Richard's answer below re: Audiobook pronunciation is almost certainly the correct answer (and when I read the book, I always read it as David, despite not making the connection to the roman numeral); if l33t speak were intended an alternate pronunciation would be Dasid, where the 5 is representative of an S.

Comment: @Doc: Hacker pronunciation is not always consistent. I knew someone who spelled his name with a silent "3".

Comment: I take it none of you are big fans of Deadmau5.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the Jonathan Davis-narrated audiobook, the consistent pronunciation is **David** ('deɪ-vɪd').

Obviously the choice of a [l33t](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet) name (e.g. replacing one or more characters for a number) is intended to identify him to the reader as a hacker/cracker both in and out-of-universe.

In this case, the letter v (which corresponds with the Roman numeral **V**) has been replaced with the number 5.

Comment: I'm tempted to -1 because hackers don't use 133t-speak. Script kiddies and crackers and wannabes do.

Comment: @DVK This was written before annoying crap like "133t" and all that crap. It's brilliant.

Comment: @Richard - Good Call!  I was thinking 'audiobook' as well =]

Comment: @MeatTrademark snow crash was written in 1992, this style of name dates from at least the 1950s ( 'Hen3ry' in 'An evening wasted with Tom Lehrer', released in 1959 )

Comment: @dvk - edit just 4 u

Comment: @PeteKirkham Oh no! I'm old! I've fallen into my first "When I was younger" craptrap. ; (

Comment: It's 1337, not 133t, you noobs :)

Comment: @Richard:   What the heck does "appears superficially similar to" mean?   Only the most pedantic would argue that "the Roman numeral V" is not a letter V, and I'm pretty sure no Romans would have argued that way.   Sure, the concept of five is different than the numeral 5 or V, but in script form, which is what we are discussing, the Roman numeral for five is a letter V.

Comment: @thepopmachine - it's not pedantry, it's accuracy. The roman number V is not the same as the letter v. They don't share a common root

Comment: @Richard:   Wikipedia: Roman numerals, the numeric system used in ancient Rome, employs combinations of letters from the Latin alphabet to signify values.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: read the rest of that Wikipedia article, especially the first paragraph on the history: "Although Roman numerals came to be written with letters of the Roman alphabet, they were originally independent symbols. The Etruscans, for example, used I, Λ, X, ⋔, 8, ⊕, for I, V, X, L, C, and M, of which only I and X happened to be letters in their alphabet."

Comment: @Richard Sorry but no. The Roman numeral for 5 is not some shape that looks like a letter V; it *is* a letter V.

Comment: @MeatTrademark No and not by a long way. *Snow Crash* was published in 1992; "leetspeak" was around on BBSes in the early 1980s.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Are you happy with the edit?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Already covered in the comments and the answer. No need to rub it in.

Comment: To clarify what I meant above is that it was before 1337-speak was **SO PREVALENT**. Before people were saying "LOL" in a conversation **IRL**. Before it killed the notion we should still write like we are not idiots who have never read a book. **THAT'S** what I meant. The dumbing-down hipster BS that permeates our culture. 1992 was NOWHERE NEAR AS BAD as now. It had hints, but now it's like a virus that eats intelligence while crapping out laziness and near-incoherence.

Comment: @Richard:   Honestly this wording seems like a non-committal compromise because it seems to imply that "the Roman numeral V" is not a "letter V".   But is has to do with want exactly is meant by "corresponds to" which is a vague verb.   This would go away if it said "which is the Roman numeral for five".

Comment: @ThePopMachine Don't let the Unicode consortium hear you talk like that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_numerals#Roman_numerals

Comment: @fluffy:   Read on. "One reason for the existence of pre-combined numbers is to facilitate the setting of multiple-letter numbers (such as VIII) in a single "square" in Asian vertical text. Another reason is for 12-hour clock-face use."   These are special cases.

Comment: THIS COMMENT THREAD IS AMAZING.

Answer (score 23):

*Disclaimer: I haven't read the books so this is just a guess.*

Since **5** is **V** in Roman numerals, I'm guessing **"David"**.

Comment: I don't recall it ever being explicitly stated in the book, but this is how I've always pronounced it in my head.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's speculation from someone who's admittedly not even read the material in question -- at best it qualifies as a comment (and, in fact, you did make it a comment -- why then turn what's clearly not up to snuff for a full-fledged answer into one?). It's good as a comment, but completely unsuitable as an answer.

Comment: @Kromey: I don't see any reason *not* to speculate in an answer as long as it is not wild speculation. This happens here all the time! It's fine as long as it is explained and *as long as it is clear that it is only speculation*. As to why I made it an answer, see my comment above.

Comment: @Wikis I'm all for speculative answers, and have upvoted it and even done it myself -- "I've never read it but I'm guessing", however, isn't speculation, it's guessing, and in response to a question asking specifically about "word of god" guidance is wholly inappropriate. Trying to properly convey my objection in the cramped spaces of a comment lead to using ambiguous shorthand initially, though, so for that I apologize.

Comment: @Kromey: no worries, you have nothing to apologise for. But I don't think there is a difference between [speculation and guessing](http://www.italki.com/question/220218). We will have to agree to differ.

Comment: @Wikis The difference is that speculation is based on something (in this case, roman numerals), while guessing is not (such as, "I think it's pronounced Daquid" with no reasoning given)

Comment: OK guys, now you've got me wondering. I think the answer is correct but perhaps I should have used *speculate* rather than *guess*. [Let's ask the experts](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/173516/1682)! @Izkata

Comment: @Kromey - did you know that in your first comment you wrote *"it's speculation"* and in the second wrote, *"[it] isn't speculation"* :) [I'm trying to work out the difference myself](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/173516/1682).

Comment: @Wikis Like I said in my last comment, I erred in expressing myself correctly initially.

Answer (score -2):

There's another (though highly unlikely) possibility. To be able to send text (SMS) messages on phones that were not Arabic enabled, Arab teenagers created a system using the Roman alphabet and the numbers 3,5,7 and 9 to represent sounds not found in English.

'5' is, more or less, an aspirated 'h' sound.

The beauty of their system is that you can write Arabic perfectly well in it, and from left to right as well.

But I doubt that Stephenson had this in mind.

Comment: This is interesting but largely irrelevant to the question asked. At most it should have been a comment.

Comment: Yech. I hate Arabeezy even more than 733t.

Comment: Sure it does; it suggests that another pronunciation is treating the 5 as a hard "h" or Spanish "jota" sound. How is this not answering the question?

Comment: @user26732 - Well, firstly because there's no canon reason to assume that Stephenson knew anything about this piece of SMS esoterica

Comment: @Richard: And there's no reason to assume that he didn't know. We don't know one way or another.

Comment: If all we're doing is making unjustified guesses then you might just as well conclude that it was a spellcheck error.

Comment: Not when there is a substantial group that uses the number 5 (and 3,5,7) to provide sounds when using the Roman alphabet. Such use is a fact. Frank Herbert makes free use of Arabic in Dune--and who would have thought that if you don't speak Hebrew you miss the 'Kazakh' language jokes in Borat?